# Sorting an array which contains string object in react

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, indexing

I'm retrieving the data from the radio button checked for database purposes and I wanted to check the string objects index are equal to the api response string object from the db. The user can select the radio button in any order, but finally I wanted to sort the radio button with respect to get api response

Since, I'm new to react, I am trying to start off with...

I have attached the response below

```
    data:
     matrix:
      option_questions: Array(10)
        0: {text: "Hai"}
        1: {text: "Hello"}
        2: {text: "Hola"}
      options: Array(10)
        0: {text: "1"}
        1: {text: "2"}
        2: {text: "3"}
```

After checking the radio button values, my array goes likes this...

```
0:
 id: "3"
 qn: "Hello"
1:
 id: "1"
 qn: "Hola"
2:
 id: "2"
 qn: "Hai"
```

Here, I have to rearrange the array using the qn object index only like below format..

```
    0:
     id: "2"
     qn: "Hai"
    1:
     id: "3"
     qn: "Hello"
    2:
     id: "1"
     qn: "Hola"
```

This is my code for on change

```
changeRadioHandler = (event) => {
    const qn = event.target.name;
    const id = event.target.value;      
    const question = {
      id: event.target.value,
      qn      
    };
    if (this.state.questions.some((question) => question.qn === qn)) {
      questions = [
        ...this.state.questions.filter((question) => question.qn !== qn),
        question,
      ];
    } else {
      questions = [...this.state.questions, question];
    }    
    const comparator = (a, b) => a.qn.localCompare(b.qn);
    console.log(questions.sort(comparator), "comparator");
    questions.sort(comparator);
    this.setState({ questions });
    console.log(questions);    
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a comparator function to compare the `qn` properties of each element and do a [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) comparison.

```
const comparator = (a, b) => a.qn.localeCompare(b.qn);
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "3",
    qn: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    qn: "Hola"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    qn: "Hai"
  },
];

const comparator = (a, b) => a.qn.localeCompare(b.qn);

console.log(data.sort(comparator));
```

Comment: Getting error like this
TypeError: question.sort is not a function

Comment: @skp My solution is based solely on your example arrays. What is `question`? You can't sort object properties, you sort array elements.

Comment: question is an object where I store the id and qn

Comment: @skp Why are you trying to sort the question element? If you update your question with your *actual* data object then a more accurate answer can be provided.

Comment: Can I have an example?

Comment: @skp You've a typo, it's `questions.sort(comparator)`, not `question.sort(comparator)`; `questions` is the array.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'qn' of undefined -- Getting this error now!

Comment: @skp Your question elements are `{ id: "..", qn: "..." }`, there's no `question` property, so ***not*** `{ question: { id: "..", qn: "..." } }`.

Comment: TypeError: a.qn.localCompare is not a function  -- Getting this error now!

Comment: @skp Then *some* element within `questions` is missing a `qn` property. What is `questions`? It isn't declared within `changeRadioHandler`.

Comment: questions is the array declared outside the on change function.

Comment: @skp Please try to verify each element in both `questions` and `this.state.questions` to ensure all elements have the required properties, namely `qn` such that it can be accessed for the sorting.